# Python and JSON - TypeError list indices must be integers not str

Tags: python, json

I am learning to use Python and APIs (specifically, this World Cup API, http://www.kimonolabs.com/worldcup/explorer)

The JSON data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Nicolas Alexis Julio",
    "lastName": "N'Koulou N'Doubena",
    "nickname": "N. N'Koulou",
    "assists": 0,
    "clubId": "5AF524A1-830C-4D75-8C54-2D0BA1F9BE33",
    "teamId": "DF25ABB8-37EB-4C2A-8B6C-BDA53BF5A74D",
    "id": "D9AD1E6D-4253-4B88-BB78-0F43E02AF016",
    "type": "Player"
  },

 {
    "firstName": "Alexandre Dimitri",
    "lastName": "Song-Billong",
    "nickname": "A. Song",
    "clubId": "35BCEEAF-37D3-4685-83C4-DDCA504E0653",
    "teamId": "DF25ABB8-37EB-4C2A-8B6C-BDA53BF5A74D",
    "id": "A84540B7-37B6-416F-8C4D-8EAD55D113D9",
    "type": "Player"
  },
   ]
```

I am simply trying to print all of the firstNames in this API.  Here's what I have:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = "http://worldcup.kimonolabs.com/api/players?apikey=xxx"
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url).read
readable_json = json.dumps(json_obj)
playerstuff = readable_json['firstName']
for i in playerstuff:
    print i['firstName']
```

But when I run it, I get the error "...line 8, in ...TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

I have looked around for solutions, but seem to find questions to more "in depth" API questions and I don't really understand it all yet, so any help or explanation as to what I need to do would be amazing.  Thank you!

Comment: Just some common python wisdom - the requests library http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ is usually a much better alternative to using urllib2.

Comment: Instead of the url cant i not read something like: @app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST']) def foo():
    json_obj = request.json
    readable_json = json.loads(json_obj)
    for i in readable_json:
        print i['firstName']   if i do the same, i get TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First of all, you should be using `json.loads`, not `json.dumps`.  `loads` converts JSON source text to a Python value, while `dumps` goes the other way.

After you fix that, based on the JSON snippet at the top of your question, `readable_json` will be a list, and so `readable_json['firstName']` is meaningless.  The correct way to get the `'firstName'` field of every element of a list is to eliminate the `playerstuff = readable_json['firstName']` line and change `for i in playerstuff:` to `for i in readable_json:`.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you for your explanations, that did the trick.  Now, to get greedy, how can I also print the 'lastName', next to the first name with a space?

And if you have any recommendations on a tutorial (starting simple) of python and APIs I am all ears!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3718365: `print i['firstName'], i['lastName']`

Comment: Thanks! One final question that should get me on my way:  If I wanted to list all of the possible keys (ie: firstName, lastName, age, etc.) so the user can type what they want to look at, how would I return a list of the keys (is that the right word)?  

Also, I'm new to StackOverflow so sorry if I shouldn't be adding questions onto questions.

Comment: @user3718365: You shouldn't be adding questions onto questions, but your first extra question was trivial, and I'm in a good-ish mood.  The simplest way to get a list of keys is `readable_json[0].keys()`, but this assumes that every element of the list has the same set of keys, which isn't always true.

Comment: What's the downside of `readable_json = json.loads(json_obj)[0]`?

Answer (score 35):

I solved changing

```
readable_json['firstName']
```

by

```
readable_json[0]['firstName']
```

Comment: hi = json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])

ji = json.loads(hi),  ji[0]["foo"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify your code down to

```
url = "http://worldcup.kimonolabs.com/api/players?apikey=xxx"
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url).read
player_json_list = json.loads(json_obj)
for player in readable_json_list:
    print player['firstName']
```

You were trying to access a list element using dictionary syntax. the equivalent of

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4]
foo["1"]
```

It can be confusing when you have lists of dictionaries and keeping the nesting in order.