# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str by json data

Tags: python, json, json2html

The whole code means scan all json files( 300+) and converter json to html.

But some titles have some special characters, I have replace those first.

But

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
 File ".\json2html.py", line 30, in <module>
    d["title"] = re.sub("[|\^&+\-%*?/=!>]", "-", d["title"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**I've already googled 3 hours, but no solution for my case** ,
such as this one:
[Parsing JSON with Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855276/parsing-json-with-python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str)

[Python and JSON - TypeError list indices must be integers not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708634/python-and-json-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str?rq=1)

**my Code :**

```
import json
import re
from glob import glob

for file_name in glob("*.json"):
    fi = open(file_name, 'r')
    data = json.load(fi)   
    
    for a in data.values():
        for d in a:
            d["title"] = re.sub("[|\^&+\-%*?/=!>]", "-", d["title"]) 

    fo = open(data["title"] + ".html", 'w')
    fo.write(str(data["body_html"]))
    fi.close()
    fo.close()
```

**I tried :**

```
   for a in data:
        a["title"] = re.sub("[|\^&+\-%*?/=!>]", "-", a["title"])
```

But still got error.

**Tried :**

```
 dataTitle = data[0]["title"]
 dataTitle = re.sub("[|\^&+\-%*?/=!>]", "-", dataTitle ) 

 fo = open(dataTitle + ".html", 'w')
```

**still got error:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".\json2html.py", line 28, in <module>
        dataTitle = data[0]["title"]
    KeyError: 0
```

**Json :**

```
{
  "body_html": "<div><head></head><body><div class=\"lake-content-editor-core lake-engine lake-typography-traditional\" data-lake-element=....</a></div></div></body></div>",
  "slug": 6643849,
  "title": "idea/project?task->things<-tools%"
}
```

**Sample json file:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ks9cc1qzegc7t5j/cq4coz.json?dl=0

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Okay I updated. Pls check . Thank you !

Comment: @Kanglando ```d``` is a ```list``` not a ```dictionary```. To make sure you are doing the right thing just do ```print(type(d))``` and see what is the type of ```d```. Do it after this line: ```for d in a:```

Comment: @iliya  `print(type(d))` - > `<class 'str'>`  ????

Comment: you could also use `print(d)` to see what you get in `d` - maybe it will help to understand what is wrong.

Comment: you use `data.values()` so you get only `values` without `keys` - and this way you can't use `data[key] = new_value`. And for your example JSON you need only `data['title'] = new_value` without any `for`-loop. If you work with more complex JSON then you should show it in question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate inside your json since it's a single object:

```
data = json.load(fi)   
data["title"] = re.sub("[|\^&+\-%*?/=!>]", "-", data["title"])
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried this before. Still the same error.

Comment: It works for your posted json, try posting the json you get an error for.

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted, otherwise post a new issue/json in the question.

Comment: I'm going to close it . Bcz I change the way find those special characters of json file, and manually rename them.