# Extract data from GCP source ips JSON file

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to setup in GCP a firewall rule in my VPC setting, using as a source all the Google IPs used by the monitoring, GCP allow to download the following txt file

```
[{"ipAddress":"104.155.77.122","region":"EUROPE","location":"Belgium"},{"ipAddress":"104.155.110.139","region":"EUROPE","location":"Belgium"},{"ipAddress":"146.148.119.250","region":"EUROPE","location":"Belgium"},{"ipAddress":"35.195.128.75","region":"EUROPE","location":"Belgium"},{"ipAddress":"35.240.124.58","region":"EUROPE","location":"Belgium"},{"ipAddress":"35.205.234.10","region":"EUROPE","location":"Belgium"},{"ipAddress":"35.205.72.231","region":"EUROPE","location":"Belgium"},{"ipAddress":"35.187.114.193","region":"EUROPE","location":"Belgium"},{"ipAddress":"35.205.205.242","region":"EUROPE","location":"Belgium"},{"ipAddress":"35.187.242.246","region":"ASIA_PACIFIC","location":"Singapore"},{"ipAddress":"35.186.144.97","region":"ASIA_PACIFIC","location":"Singapore"},{"ipAddress":"35.198.221.49","region":"ASIA_PACIFIC","location":"Singapore"},{"ipAddress":"35.198.194.122","region":"ASIA_PACIFIC","location":"Singapore"},{"ipAddress":"35.198.248.66","region":"ASIA_PACIFIC","location":"Singapore"},{"ipAddress":"35.185.178.105","region":"ASIA_PACIFIC","location":"Singapore"},{"ipAddress":"35.198.224.104","region":"ASIA_PACIFIC","location":"Singapore"},{"ipAddress":"35.240.151.105","region":"ASIA_PACIFIC","location":"Singapore"},{"ipAddress":"35.186.159.51","region":"ASIA_PACIFIC","location":"Singapore"},{"ipAddress":"146.148.59.114","region":"USA","location":"Iowa"},{"ipAddress":"23.251.144.62","region":"USA","location":"Iowa"},{"ipAddress":"146.148.41.163","region":"USA","location":"Iowa"},{"ipAddress":"35.239.194.85","region":"USA","location":"Iowa"},{"ipAddress":"104.197.30.241","region":"USA","location":"Iowa"},{"ipAddress":"35.192.92.84","region":"USA","location":"Iowa"},{"ipAddress":"35.238.3.7","region":"USA","location":"Iowa"},{"ipAddress":"35.224.249.156","region":"USA","location":"Iowa"},{"ipAddress":"35.238.118.210","region":"USA","location":"Iowa"},{"ipAddress":"35.197.117.125","region":"USA","location":"Oregon"},{"ipAddress":"35.203.157.42","region":"USA","location":"Oregon"},{"ipAddress":"35.199.157.7","region":"USA","location":"Oregon"},{"ipAddress":"35.233.206.171","region":"USA","location":"Oregon"},{"ipAddress":"35.197.32.224","region":"USA","location":"Oregon"},{"ipAddress":"35.233.167.246","region":"USA","location":"Oregon"},{"ipAddress":"35.203.129.73","region":"USA","location":"Oregon"},{"ipAddress":"35.185.252.44","region":"USA","location":"Oregon"},{"ipAddress":"35.233.165.146","region":"USA","location":"Oregon"},{"ipAddress":"35.186.164.184","region":"USA","location":"Virginia"},{"ipAddress":"35.188.230.101","region":"USA","location":"Virginia"},{"ipAddress":"35.199.27.30","region":"USA","location":"Virginia"},{"ipAddress":"35.186.176.31","region":"USA","location":"Virginia"},{"ipAddress":"35.236.207.68","region":"USA","location":"Virginia"},{"ipAddress":"35.236.221.2","region":"USA","location":"Virginia"},{"ipAddress":"35.221.55.249","region":"USA","location":"Virginia"},{"ipAddress":"35.199.12.162","region":"USA","location":"Virginia"},{"ipAddress":"35.186.167.85","region":"USA","location":"Virginia"},{"ipAddress":"35.199.66.47","region":"SOUTH_AMERICA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil"},{"ipAddress":"35.198.18.224","region":"SOUTH_AMERICA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil"},{"ipAddress":"35.199.67.79","region":"SOUTH_AMERICA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil"},{"ipAddress":"35.198.36.209","region":"SOUTH_AMERICA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil"},{"ipAddress":"35.199.90.14","region":"SOUTH_AMERICA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil"},{"ipAddress":"35.199.123.150","region":"SOUTH_AMERICA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil"},{"ipAddress":"35.198.39.162","region":"SOUTH_AMERICA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil"},{"ipAddress":"35.199.77.186","region":"SOUTH_AMERICA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil"},{"ipAddress":"35.199.126.168","region":"SOUTH_AMERICA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil"}]
```

What I need is to extract all ip address to a list, for later create the firewall rule using gcloud or python, the following code is what I tried but I'm getting errors

```
import json


with open("test.json") as jsonFile:
    jsonObject = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonFile.close()

ips = jsonObject['ipAddress']

print(ips)


    C:\Scripts\Python\GCP\listipaddresses> python3 .\listips.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Scripts\Python\GCP\listipaddresses\listips.py", line 8, in <module>
    product = jsonObject['ipAddress']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can anyone could help me how to achieve this?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

`ipAddress` is not an element of the list, you should iterate over the complete list.

```py
import json

with open("test.json") as jsonFile:
    jsonObject = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonFile.close()

ips = []

for items in jsonObject:
    ips.append(str(items['ipAddress']))

print(ips)
```

I'd suggest to check better the basics of Python and investigate more about this error, there are several posts about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708634/python-and-json-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str).